# Check if $request is empty or not in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, stripe-payments, e-commerce

I have a user detail page when he'll add his details than he can go to checkout page to enter card details.

Routes for detail page

```php
Route::get('/checkout', 'CheckoutController@index')->name('checkout.index')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/checkout', 'CheckoutController@store')->name('checkout.store');
```

When he'll add these information, he can access to payment page like this:

```php
Route::get('/checkout/payment', 'CheckoutController@payment')->name('checkout.payment');
Route::post('/checkout/payment', 'CheckoutController@paymentstore')->name('payment.store');
```

I want to redirect user to `/checkout` page if user try to access directly to `/checkout/payment` without adding information.

My Controller

```php
public function payment() {
    if(Cart::instance('default')->count() > 0) {
        if($request) {
            return view('checkoutpayment');
        }

        return redirect()->route('Checkout.index')
            ->withError('Please add your personal details to complete the checkout.');
    }

    return redirect()->route('cart.index')
        ->withError('You have nothing in your cart, please add some products first');
  }
```

Comment: `$request` is never set, you need to make it available first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$request` only available for single request so you cannot get data on the payment page. But `session` definitely helps you so first of all you have to store your user data in session using `$request->session()` and then you have to check whether data is available on the payment page or not using `$request->session()->has()` method.